# Java RejectedExecutionException on ProcessBuilder.start

Tags: java, unix, process, processbuilder

**EDIT**

> After some digging, I found out that there is a test that runs some code which replaces some implementation-defined bits with custom ones (using reflection to do so), with the cleanup causing termination of the executor. That solves my problem, but doesn't feel worthy of an answer.
>
> I am still wondering though, after a bunch more CI runs, I've realized that two runners ran into this error every time, but the last one never did, and my VM did it at random. That however would be a separate question if I ever care to post it.
>
> As such, I shall attempt to close this question, as I no longer consider it relevant.

I've ran into a weird problem recently. Right away, I can't provide an MCVE, as the problem happens in a CI run and I've had trouble recreating it locally, as well as not always happening in CI.

This exception occurs on ProcessBuilder.start() during a specific test, though in live operation all seems to run fine.

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.lang.UNIXProcess$$Lambda$7/108449608@4814a677 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@71e6bac0[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.initStreams(UNIXProcess.java:288)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.lambda$new$2(UNIXProcess.java:258)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:257)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at place.where.processbuilder.start.is.called.during.test...
```

CI runs a Maven build on a CentOS7, so far the exception happened 3 out of 4 times, locally I'm running the same build on a CentOS7, I've only had it happen 1 out of 2 times, and never when the test suite is reduced to only the test where it occurs (by specifying the test name to maven), in over 10 runs.

All search for RejectedExecutionException leads me to posts where people max out the capacity on their own pool, however this seems to be Java's internal pool that for some reason appears to be terminated.

I'm wondering what could be terminating the pool to begin with, but have no idea how to trace an internal implementation-defined thing right now. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This is indeed curious, I've not seen that yet. Are you by chance starting many external processes concurrently here?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Honestly not really sure, I don't know how exactly Maven runs the stages, but the particular test should only ever try to start one process.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's no longer relevant, but I don't want to delete outright yet

Comment: It would be equally fine to write up your findings as an answer, but that's definitely not required (especially since this is a self-produced issue that's unlikely to happen in the exact same way to others).

Comment: @JoachimSauer That was pretty much exactly why I didn't feel it was worth making it a full-fledged anwser. I feel like my findings invalidate the question rather than answer it per say.